# Is there any awesome way to left each of individual elements from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

i want to make some efficient Javascript code.
if there's a array like [a1, b2, a1, c3, .. , b2, c5, .. ,c3], the result that i want to make is [a1, b2, c3, c5].
In summary, I want to get an array containing only one of each individual element of the original array.
is there any good way that is more efficient than FULL SCAN?
(i mean more efficient than the code like

```
for (var i=0; i < origArray.length; i++) {
  if (!tempArray.includes(origArray[i])) {
    tempArray.push(array[i]);
  }
}
```

)
thanks.

Comment: what did you mean by efficiency? Better time complexity or shorter code to write?
If it's latter, you can do const temArray = [...new Set(origArray)]  Assuming origArray contains only number or string

Comment: @CharlieNg oh efficiency that i mentioned means **better time complexity**. thanks for your comment.

Comment: @CharlieNg That's probably also the faster option since `Set` will have been implemented in native language, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. You can sort the array first and then only keep each item one time. It's more code but the time complexity is **O(n log(n))**

```js
let arr = ['a1', 'b2', 'a1', 'c3', 'b2', 'c5','c3'];

arr.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a < b) return -1;
    if(a > b) return 1;
    return 0;
})
let currentItem = '';
let output = [];
arr.forEach(function (item) {
  if (currentItem != item) {
    output.push(item)
    currentItem = item;
  }
})
console.log(output)
```